# Does application.yml support environment variables?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, spring-boot

I tried using env variables in my application.yml configration like:

```
spring:
  main:
    show_banner: false

---

spring:
  profiles: production
server:
  address: $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP
  port: $OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT
```

but the env variables are not resolved. Do I have to provide a different notation?

In Rails you can e.g. use <%= ENV['FOOVAR'] %>

The only alternative is to run the app like:

```
java -jar my.jar --server.address=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP --server.port=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Try `${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}` (the usual Spring placeholder notation). See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) for docs.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed:
`app.name=MyApp
app.description=${app.name} is a Spring Boot application`

Comment: Just to point out - if you're using kotlin, you need to put your reference in quotes & escape the `$` eg
`root: "\${LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT:info}"`

Comment: Guys, how can we go about passing the OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT through unix cli when starting the application? I know we can use -D to pass override parameters, but does that also work for env variables? Ex.: nohup java -Xmx1024m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active="whatever". Is there a way to do that with env vars?

Comment: @IgorDonin, would concatenation of variable assignments and program call an option for you? E. g.: `$MY_ENV=value && java -jar ...`

Comment: @IgorDonin you can just prefix the command with an assignment to the environment variable.  For example:  ```OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT=1234 java -jar myapp.jar```

Answer (score 148):

You even can add default value, if environment variable not provided:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ${LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT:info}
```

Comment: I found this syntax in an app I inherited and have been unable to find the Spring docs that show this.  It is fairly obvious what is happening, but to be able to find the docs for it would be nice.  Thank you for sharing - I am more confident with my conclusion now.

Comment: Is using *default values* in configuration UB or is it explicitly stated possible?

Comment: does this syntax chain? can one do `${MY_EXPECTED_VALUE:${${MY_ENV}_my_expected_prefix:default_value}}`

would be nice to read the docs on this

Comment: can i have semicolons in my default value?

Comment: is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I've found that this (and the accepted answer) works for Micronaut's application.yml as well.

Comment: Can we make env variable mandatory ? Thanks!

Comment: @DaveAnkin syntax can be chained. i just tried out: `spring.datasource.url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/${spring.application.name}}`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given. You can use your IDE like `IntelliJ` to provide the env variables, you can do that as the following

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In summary YES. You can use the @Value to load the environment variables from the **application.yml** or **application.properties**

Additionally, you can load variables and cast them automatically if you need different data types to perform your validations and business logic.

```
server:
  address: ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}
  port: ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}
```

Load information

```
@Value("${server.address}")
private String serverAddress;

@Value("${server.port}")
private Integer serverPort;
```