# Using variables with YAML in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, yaml, json5

Is there any way to parse data to a `.yaml` file in node.js? I've been searching about this for hours and found nothing useful.

Let's say I have a string in a `.yaml` file:

```
message: Hello, ${user.fullName}, have a nice day.
```

As I've been reading, there's something called "placeholders" but it seems only available in spring framework.

[This is what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148748/how-to-use-property-placeholders-in-yml-file/43279822).

And in other places, they use a different syntax like `{{user.fullName}}`

So, is there any way to replace `${user.fullName}` with an actual value in node.js? I don't know if I should manually handle this thing that they call "placeholder" myself with `string.replace()`. I checked the main YAML docs and there's nothing called "placeholder" or even "variable" in their entire docs!

But, similarly, I can achieve a similar result with `pug.js` using `#{user.fullName}` (with `#` instead) and then call something like: `pug.renderFile('template.pug', {fullName: 'Timothy'})`. Check `pug.js` [docs](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for more details.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just run it through a template system before parsing? https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-template-strings

Comment: Thanks! That's something to start with. Still, I'm looking for the best practice for this (if there's any).